# Adding a range between 2 words in regex

Tags: java, android, regex

i have the following regex

`(?i)(?:\\bauthority\\b).*(?i)(?:\\bmilitary\\b)`

which means two words "authority" and "military" are found in order in which "authority" is the first in the occurrence.

Using the pattern and matcher methods in java, the regex returns true for the following string

> Never question the authority of celestial's magnificent but overconfident military

Which works for that purpose.

My question is, i want to add range in the following regex in the sense of authority (N-words range) military.

In the example above, if the N-words range is 5 then it should return true. It is because there are 5 words between authority and military **"of celestial's magnificent but overconfident"**. If the N-words range is 3, it must return false. It should also return true if the N-words range is 6 or higher.

I know i need to add something after the `authority\\b)` part of the regex but i dont know what to add exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you right this should do it:

```
(?i)\bauthority(?: +\S+){0,5} +military\b
```

(No java escapes)

It makes sure there are 5 words between the surrounding ones.

[Check this example at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cZ3wH6/4).

Hope it helps.

Regards

**Edit:**

<strike>Changed the regex to allow **5 or more** words in the range. (And for clarity in the regex101 example, only space, not any white space - `\s`, between words.)</strike>

OK I'll give it a last go :) If you wan't to reverse the effect of the range, i.e. `<=5`, set the minimum and the maximum count like `{0,5}` allowing 0 to 5 words in between. If there should be at least one word - `{1,5}`. Changed the regex. Hope I got you right this time.

Comment: Never knew about the capital `S` to match non white space characters. Guess my regex skills are a bit lacking =P

Comment: Hi, it works but it doesnt need to be exact. If i put 6 as range it must return true too. Sorry late changes

Comment: Do you mean - if you put 6 words, it should return true? Or do you mean that you want to be able to test for 6 as well? I changed the regex to allow for *5 or more* - `{5,}` if that's what you meant. If you mean to be able to test for other numbers than 5, format the regex putting whatever number you need instead of the `{5}`.

Comment: Hi not the words but the range, if i put 50 for example it should return true if the words between word1 and word2 are less than or equal to 50. Thus if i put 3 for example, and the words between word1 and word2 are 10 words apart it should return false. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex

```
(?i)(?:\bauthority\b)\s+(?:[^\s]+\s){5,}(?:\bmilitary\b)
```

Broken into parts we have

```
(?i)(?:\bauthority\b)  - from your origional regex
\s+                    - match a space
  (?:[^\s]+\s)         - Match a word, defined as a 1 or more characters which isnt a space followed by a space
  {5}                  - Match that "word" exactly 5 times
(?:\bmilitary\b)       - The word military
```

Comment: Hi @ug_ ,  it doesnt need to be exact. If i put 6 or higher value as range it must return true too. Sorry late changes

Comment: @ReubenJaMesAveñoGruta No worries, you can use a different range. For instance for 5 or more use `{5,}`. Or if you want between something like 5 and 7 you could do `{5,7}`

Comment: Hi @ug_ your example returns true no matter what range i specify

Answer (score 0):

Something try [this](https://regex101.com/r/aA4eS2/2).

```
(?i)(?:\bauthority\b)(?:\s[^\s]+){5}\s(?i)(?:\bmilitary\b)
```